# create HTML using javascript recursive function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a recursive function in Javascript which should basically give me HTML like BELOW

```
 <li><a class="expand">+</a> <span class="treeNodeInner"><a id="7471">Ringtones</a>
            <ul>
                <li><span class="treeNodeInner"><a id="7995">Top Tones</a></span></li>
                <li><span class="treeNodeInner"><a id="8642">Country</a></span></li>
                <li><span class="treeNodeInner"><a id="8640">Rock</a></span></li>
            </ul>
        </span></li>
```

I am using the below function to make the above html using javascript.
Its basically a tree view were we will have nodes and sub nodes kind of thing.

I am struggling the achieve the above HTML structure through below function, please advise modifications with the below function

```
function GenerateNodes(categItem) {
    var parentNode = "<li>"; //parent li
    if (categItem.SubCategory != null && categItem.SubCategory != undefined && categItem.SubCategory.Count > 0) {
        parentNode = "<li><a class='expand'>+</a>";
    }
    parentNode += "<input type='radio' name='category' /><span class='treeNodeInner'><a id='" + categItem.ID + "'>" + categItem.name + "</a> "; //need to close the span

    if (categItem.SubCategory != null && categItem.SubCategory != undefined && categItem.SubCategory.Count > 0) {
        var subNode = "<span><ul>";
        for (var index = 0; index < categItem.SubCategory.Count; index++) {
            subNode += GenerateNodes(categItem.SubCategory[index]);
            subNode += "</ul></span>"
        }
        parentNode += subNode
    }
       parentNode += "</span></li>"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you, or are you not using jQuery on your code? I don't see a single reference of jQuery functionality on your samples.

Comment: well, i am not using any jquery right now but if anyone can advise me, i will use it

Comment: Instead of `categItem.SubCategory != null && categItem.SubCategory != undefined` you could just have `catagItem.SubCategory` since if it's `null` or `undefined` it will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: thanks geekchic i will make the change but that's not my issue in the question

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: Did you try using DOM manipulations instead of string injection? Another approach could be to use a javascript template engine.

Comment: try to look at this: http://pastebin.com/dddn8GhL (NOT TESTED!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply looking at the code, I found out that you are not inserting the new `li` in your html. I'm not sure if you manage this somewhere out of your code. I'd copied your code and do some debug on it. Then I try to add the `li` on the html using some code. See code below:

```
//Insert this after parentNode += "</span></li>";
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = parentNode;
categItem.appendChild(newDiv.childNodes[0]);

//I assume that categItem is the id of the container as your sample html code
//above is not clear to me. So I did using sample html below
<div id="liContainer">
</div>
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWYyk/) how the above code work. I know this is not exactly what you want, but I hope you can get some idea from this.